# Django MySQL Manual Full Text Search Code Location

Tags: python, mysql, django

The Django docs mention that this was removed in 1.10 because it was too database specific and has been replaced with this :

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#search-query-lookup)

```
from django.db import models

class Search(models.Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'search'

    def as_mysql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return 'MATCH (%s) AGAINST (%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)' % (lhs, rhs), params

models.CharField.register_lookup(Search)
models.TextField.register_lookup(Search)
```

Does anyone know where this code belongs in the project structure so it will be executed at the right time?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter in the slightest, as long as you import it from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has come across this issue here is the documentation on where to put it. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/#a-simple-lookup-example)

> You could place the implementation in a models.py file, or register the lookup in the ready() method of an AppConfig.

In practice I just put it on the bottom of my `models.py` file.